# Why iTC app privacy policy is not optional anymore?

Tags: ios, ios-appstore, development, app-store-connect, privacy

When I open some of my apps in iTunesConnect, I see that they are require privacy policy now (the app become edited, Save button is active, privacy policy field is highlighted):
[image]
I have this problem only for particular apps. It started after iOS 10.3 update. Did I missed changes in iTunes Connect?

Comment: Do you collect any user data in your app?

Comment: @fsb, no, I don't.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, I found answer by myself:

https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#privacy

> Apps that collect user or usage data must have a privacy policy and secure user consent for the collection. This includes—but isn’t limited to—apps that implement HealthKit or other health/medical technologies, HomeKit, Keyboard extensions, Apple Pay, Stickers and iMessage extensions, include a login, or access user data from the device (e.g. location, contacts, calendar, etc.).

My app is using HealthKit for workouts on Apple Watch (but not collect any data).

Comment: I should've been more specific, health kit actually does collect user data whether you're using it or not.

Comment: Scary! Some of the guidelines are optional!  For example, when they use the word *should* they mean *should* - its optional. Facebook, for example, doesn’t follow some of the *should*s WRT (iii)Data minimization as applied to photo access... at least unless an extremely tortured definition of “core functionality” is used: